# Yaml validation error on TaskDefinition preventing cloudformation from reaching completion

Tags: amazon-web-services, yaml, aws-cloudformation, amazon-ecs

I'm trying to create a cloudformation for a Task Definition but I keep running into validation errors on the **command** portion of the Task Definition. I've tried a few approaches and can't seem to get it right.

I've been following the documentation [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-ecs-taskdefinition.html#aws-resource-ecs-taskdefinition--examples).

Below are 2 of my main attempts and their respective errors:

```yaml
Command: !Sub 
         - "--config config.yaml --env ${environment}"
         - { environment: !FindInMap [EnvironmentVariables, !Ref Environment, Environment] }
Environment] }
```

Error:

> #/ContainerDefinitions/0/Command: expected type: JSONArray, found: String)

```yaml
Command: !Sub 
      - [--config, config.yaml, --env, ${environment}]
      - { environment: !FindInMap [EnvironmentVariables, !Ref Environment, Environment] }
```

> Template format error: YAML not well-formed.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be some issue with how !Sub interacts with a Yaml list but I'm not exactly sure what causes this to be the case.

However the below piece of Yaml managed to solve my problem.

```yaml
Command:
        - --config 
        - config.yaml
        - --env 
        - !FindInMap [EnvironmentVariables, !Ref Environment, Environment]
```